# What is guard size in Posix?

Tags: memory, stack, posix, stack-overflow

This question is inspired by the `pthread_attr_setguardsize` and `pthread_attr_getguardsize` methods within the pthread API. The documentation for the method can be found [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_attr_getguardsize.html).

In the documentation for these methods, the closest I came to finding an explanation of what guard size actually is was this:

> The guardsize attribute controls the size of the guard area for the created thread's stack. The guardsize attribute provides protection against overflow of the stack pointer. If a thread's stack is created with guard protection, the implementation allocates extra memory at the overflow end of the stack as a buffer against stack overflow of the stack pointer. If an application overflows into this buffer an error shall result (possibly in a SIGSEGV signal being delivered to the thread).

I'm sure this makes perfect sense to someone but I'm still a little lost.

I understand that the guard is an overflow buffer at the end of the stack that is designed to prevent stack overflow. However I am left with two questions:

1. Why would having a special overflow buffer be preferable to simply using a larger stack?
2. If overflowing the guard still dispatches an error to the thread what is even the point of having an overflow buffer?

I'm sure there's some short, conceptual thing that answers both these questions and I'm hoping someone here is able to provide it. Thanks to everyone!

**P.S. It's also super fun that I can finally tag a question with "stack-overflow".**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The next question is what comes after the stack of a thread.

It could be anything. It could be the top of the stack of another thread, part of the heap. Some memory mapped file, etc.

If there was no guard memory, a thread could overflow its stack into that area, and if that memory is writable, there's nothing stopping the thread to overwrite that memory without generating any error/trap/signal.

You could allocate a larger stack. But how large is large enough ? If you allocate it too large, it means less available memory for anything else (especially on 32 bit systems where the memory space is quite limited)

A guard area attempts to solve this. This area would be marked as non writable, thus the kernel, with hardware assistance will get notified if someone attempts to write to that area (i.e. a thread overflowed its stack), send a signal to the process and (by default) terminate it.

Killing the process is normally better compared to risking a thread silently damaging memory it's not supposed to.

Comment: This makes perfect sense to me, thank you. However, if you don't mind a small question for clarification, you are saying that if the memory after the stack is writeable and there is no guard then a stack overflow might not even be detected? Or are you saying the memory after the stack might be corrupted before the error signal is sent?

Comment: That's right, it might not be detected - why would it ? A thread is just adding an offset to a register(the stack pointer) and then accessing that memory. If that happens to extend into valid memory in the same process - but not the current threads stack, there's nothing that would notice that. Or rather, if you want to notice that, you have to do an extra check every time the stack pointer is extended . Some compilers can be told to generate code that does that - though.that has a performance cost, and might not be effective unless all the libraries you're calling also does that same check.